# zimbra: timezone not changing despite multiple attempts

Tags: zimbra, timezone

I am using Zimbra ZCS8 for my company's email service.

When any user receives or sends an email, the timezone being used is GMT-10.
My timezone (and the one I need in the email server) is GMT-5.

Despite my attempt to change this in several ways, Zimbra is still stuck on using GMT-10.

I have tried:

- changing the timezone in the Zimbra admin GUI
- changing the timezone via the CLI, using zimbra user: zmprov mc default zimbraPrefTimeZoneId '(GMT-05.00) Bogota / Lima / Quito / Rio Branco'

I checked the linux server's time, and it is correctly set to GMT-5.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your timezone at different levels within Zimbra, please check:

- Configure -> Class of Service -> default -> Preferences: Time zone
- Configure -> Domains -> 'domainname' -> General Information: Time zone
- Manage -> Accounts -> 'account name' -> Preferences: Time zone

try the commands:

- date
- date -u

there should be 5 hours difference.

Comment: these are all set to the timezone that I wish to use. However, I am still getting the wrong time.

Comment: Just to be sure, but is the user using the web interface? Or are you using other clients?

Comment: Using web interface, iphone, thunderbird, etc. The problem is with ALL USERS, not one in particular.

Answer (score 0):

The Zimbra COS attribute `zimbraPrefTimeZoneId` is only applied to users if they do not have that attribute. Make sure your account doesn't have `zimbraPrefTimeZoneId` set like so:

```
zmprov ma someaccount@domain.com -zimbraPrefTimeZoneId
```

Also, are you certain that your account is in the default COS?